# How to draw an arrow using Photoshop curvature pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to draw a simple arrow. As I understood from some tutorial, I need to use "Fill Path" or "Stroke Path" in the following image, but as you can see its inactive.

What is the next step? Also how do I add the arrow head at the end of the line?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fill and stroke in the contextual menu are *raster based*.

Use the Fill and Stroke options for **shape/vector layers** in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.

[image]

As for **arrowheads**....

To the best of my knowledge, Photoshop has **no function** to add arrowheads to path drawn with the Pen Tool. You will need to **manually** draw any arrowheads or switch to a different application capable of adding arrowheads. (You could easily create a path with an arrowhead in Illustrator then merely copy/paste it to Photoshop).

The **Line Tool** in Photoshop *does* have an option to add an arrowhead. Unfortunately, the Line Tool only draws straight lines. But, you may be able to cobble something together with that in mind.

Comment: I'd maybe add that arrowheads can be added as an option of the Line Tool: so it's possible to create a curve and then just draw the arrowheads only (for consistent size)

Comment: Thanks @SergeyKritskiy edited. I forgot about the line tool option.